# Customizable package name gradle library project

Tags: android, ant, gradle, package

I am currently using a gradle script to compile and generate a .jar library, that is eventually targeted for an android application. I have different customers that would like a specific package name, so I can't give them the library with the package name I am using.

Is there a way a can make this configurable using gradle (preferably)? I basically want to have a way I can specify the package name while (or prior to) building, resulting in a library using the new package name.

I looked online but all I could find was ways I could change package name for an app using gradle or ant. But my project is a library project.